# Does FIFA have an Online Community feature?

Tags: fifa-12

I've been playing Pro Evolution Soccer 2012 and I really like the idea behind the Online Community feature in which you create a Community, invite your friends, create tournaments, leagues and all the results are kept in record for you.

I am wondering if FIFA 12 has a similar feature and if it does, what are the pros and cons compared to PES 2012.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I havent ever played PES but Pro clubs is probably your best best, where you play as your virtual pro. You can invite friends and you make your own club, picking kits etc. You also play in cups for xp and upgrade your stadiums etc.